# assign a list after applying a method to a new list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Is it possible to apply a method, for example remove, append, etc., to a list and assign it to a new list?
for example I want to remove the element 2 from list A = [1,2,3,4] and have a list B as [1,3,4]. somehow like the following:

```
B = A.remove(2)
```

How can I do this in python?

Comment: Some methods like `remove` work in place and return `None`, so you cannot do what you show. It has to be on separate lines. In addition, lists are mutable, so most likely you want to assign a copy of the list.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be

```
B = A[:]
B.remove(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy `A` to `B` using `copy.deepcopy` and then remove `2` from `B`. Here is how you do it:

```
import copy

A = [1,2,3,4]
B= copy.deepcopy(A)
B.remove(2)

print(A)
print(B)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 3, 4]
```